# Bootstrap-select multiple display issue

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-select

I have a multiple select that I activated with the following params:

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker({
        width: '100%',
        noneSelectedText: messages['nothingSelected']
});
```

I am getting some values from the database and trying to adjust the selected values of the multiple select accordingly, like this in javascript:

```
for (j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
            $("#user-input") 
                    .children()
                    .filter("[value = '" + inputArray[j] + "']")
                    .prop('selected', true);
}
```

And it works. The values are 100% selected because I tested it, but the text I get is still the `noneSelectedText` that I set. And bootstrap-select has a 'CHECKED' sign attached to all selected values, and that's missing as well. Clicking on a selected value works as intended and deselects it and from there the rendering works ok. But how can I make it show everything right from the beginning?

EDIT: doing this

```
$("#user-input") 
                .children()
                .filter("[value = '" + inputArray[j] + "']")
                .prop('selected', true)
                .change();
```

shows the values selected but the 'CHECKED' icon still doesn't show for the selected values. If anyone knows how I can fix that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my initial guess was that you needed to call .selectpicker('refresh').

I managed to replicate the behaviour you're seeing, and the solution on my end was indeed to refresh the selectpicker after the for loop.

```
for (j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
           $("#user-input") 
                .children()
                .filter("[value = '" + inputArray[j] + "']")
                .prop('selected', true);
}
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Note that you do not need to call .change() since you are refreshing the selectpicker.